# ld does not generate wrappers with --wrap=symbol

Tags: c, gcc, ld

For unit testing, I want to wrap a number of system calls: `memset()`, `open()`, `close()`, `read()`, `select()` and `ioctl()`.

When I compile with `gcc -rdynamic -m64 -Wl,--wrap=memset -Wl,--wrap=open -Wl,--wrap=close -Wl,--wrap=read -Wl,--wrap=select -Wl,--wrap=ioctl ...`, I get the error `undefined reference to '__wrap_memset'`, as expected. When I implementing `__wrap_memset`, I indeed see that it is invoked.

However, the linker does not complain about missing references to the other functions I want to wrap, and indeed my wrapped functions (`__wrap_open()`, etc.) are not invoked.

What am I missing here? Is it not possible to wrap `open()`, etc.?

Comment: It works as expected here. Can you compile a small example that invokes open(), run `nm` on the resulting binary to check if e.g. header files have transformed the open() call to another call/symbol, e.g. open64() or __open. As an additional note, you might need to add -fno-builtin-memset to prevent the compiler from transforming or inlining memset calls if you want to wrap them.

Comment: I see references to `open`, `close`, etc. Maybe I should clarify that I'm trying to wrap the calls from a .so file that I link with to generate my test executable. Am I using the wrong approach?

Comment: Is the shared object already built, and compiled/linked without the -Wl,--wrap linker flags ? if so, I'd assume(but that is just an assumption, not a fact) you can't alter these when you compile a binary that just links to that shared library. If it was a static library, you should be able though. Run nm on the shared library in any case, to verify its symbol names

Comment: It seems you're right... If I run `nm` on the executable, I don't see entries for other function that are defined in the .so file. E.g., if I wrap only `open`, I see an entry for `__wrap_open`, but not for the unwrapped `read` etc. I think I need to resort to using `LD_PRELOAD`.